# migration error with rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, migration

I created a new model, but when I run the `rake db: migrate` command, it shoots me the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 
10.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/yedidyaweiner/projects/music-app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: reason is, you have more than one `rake` gem versions, so to use the one define in your `Gem` file do as @dpk mentioned, `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: It is still giving me an error. Read my comment to @dpk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: OK, but now i am getting this: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'

Comment: Delete your Gemfile.lock, run `bundle install`, then run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

You can also update your gems by running

```
bundle update
```

Comment: OK, but now i am getting this: `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'`

Comment: mmm try deleting you gemfile. lock file and running bundle install again

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below commands

a) delete your Gemfile.lock file

b)bundle install

It should update Gemfile.lock with correct rake.

OR

a) gem uninstall rake -v 10.4.0

b) gem install rake -v 10.3.2

---

then try running 'rake db:migrate'. it should work.

Comment: when you work on more than one project then it's not good uninstall any other version

Comment: Yes I do agree with dpk, I added it as a quick fix. I have updated answer by adding a more apt process.

Comment: Just tried both solutions, but I  am still getting en error. `Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'`